# jquery - sidebar sliding issue

Tags: jquery, css

I'm creating a website with a sidebar on the left that you can display by clicking on the menu icon or by "dragging" (it is a swipe, to be honest) the same icon to the right.

Now, here the code: [codepen.io/nickimola/pen/reOBYN?editors=0010](http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/reOBYN?editors=0010)

As you can see, it closes itself when you release the mouse.

I think that the problem is due to the overlay, that by code should close the sidebar when clicked (i noticed that if you start the swipe on the icon, keep mouse button down, move the mouse on the sidebar and then release the mouse, the side bar stays in place.

here, some code (but please refer to the pen, as it is more complete):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {

        if ( $(e.target).closest('.hamburger').length > 0 ) {
              $('body').toggleClass('no-scroll');
        $('.hamburger').toggleClass('open');
        $('.leftSidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        } else if ( $(e.target).closest('.leftSidebar').length === 0 && $('.leftSidebar').hasClass('visible') ) {
              $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
        $('.hamburger').removeClass("open");
        $('.leftSidebar').removeClass("visible");
        }
    });
    $('.hamburger').swipe({
        swipeStatus: function (event, phase, direction, distance, duration, fingers) {
            if (phase == "move" && direction == "right") {
                          $('body').addClass('no-scroll');
                  $('.hamburger').addClass('open');
                    $('.leftSidebar').addClass('visible');
                return false;
            }
            if (phase == "move" && direction == "left") {
                          $('body').removeClass('no-scroll');
                  $('.hamburger').removeClass('open');
                    $('.leftSidebar').removeClass('visible');
                return false;
            }
        },
        threshold: 20
    });
});
```

for swiping i'm using this library: [jQuery.touchSwipe](https://github.com/mattbryson/TouchSwipe-Jquery-Plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is uniquely a problem with a mouse. If you drag with a mouse, as you release with the menu open, it will complete the click...

...which upon seeing that the menu is open will close it.

If you test with a touch device, you will see that a click does not complete its event and the menu operates as intended. If you happen to already be using modernizr https://modernizr.com in your project, you can simply only enable swipe for touch devices like so:

```
$('html.touch .hamburger').swipe({
```

P.S. I see that the latest versions of modernizr don't support that particular test anymore. They use the touchevents class and test instead. https://modernizr.com/docs

Comment: I actually like the idea of having a "draggable" sidebar on desktop as well. But if this is gonna cause problems, i'll just go for modernizr and enable it only on touch devices

Comment: I understand. Then you'll just need some way of detecting whether it weas a touch or pointer event that began the swipe and ignore the related click completion. There must be a library for this, I'm just not aware of it.

Comment: Do you think that something like this would work? http://jsbin.com/ijicoh/1/edit?html,css,js,output Basically detect the end of the sidebar navigation and then activate the bits that hides the sidebar if clicked on the overlay...or maybe even using a timeout?